# Odd behaviour with dotnet core authentication system using JWT tokens

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization, bearer-token

I have been testing my Web API authentication system for a while and have come across something really odd.

This are the steps I follow:

1 - I register an user and the system provides a JWT token

2 - I try to call API actions with the token and everything works as expected

3 - Now, I delete my database and rebuild it again with Add-Migration command

4 - There's no users in my database, but If I call an API action using the previous generated token (from point 1), it is accepted as a correctly authorized one. Remember, my database is clean. No users, no tokens, etc. registered.

Could anyone guess what is happening here?

Comment: It's not odd, it's expected behavior. Your tokens aren't stored in DB, check your token storge and as long the token isn't *expired* it's valid for *authentication*.

Comment: I thought the authentication step that core.net identity system does is checking the token credentials agains  the  database. And if it wasn't valid it returned a 401 and the action was not called. Isn't this what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Token owner has access to your API till token is not expired. This is default behavior of JWT token implementation. You don't need to check the database for user and his privileges. Everything inside token. So this is like **a cache**. But if you want **immediately** change user rights and access params you have 3 ways:

- Decrease of token's lifetime;
- Write middleware and check user in database when performing parsing token data;
- logout user from portal to force new login with new token;

Mostly business rules allow some delay for users in access updates or force them to re login.